# Overriding everyone except external users SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, groups, external-users

We have the group "Everyone except External Users" added to dozens of SharePoint Visitors sites across our tenant. There is a small subset of users who are external vendors that have their own internal email address for specific scenarios.

Is there a way to exclude this special "vendor" Security group from accessing the sites where "Everyone except external users" exists? Can we restrict their access without removing "Everyone except external users" or do we have to remove that group and explicitly allow every other users besides that vendor group?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to restrict the access without removing "Everyone except external users" permissions. You will have to have to remove the everyone group and grant permissions to internal users separately.

Comment: Agree with @Ganesh Sanap - MVP. Unfortunately, there is no way to exclude a specific security group from accessing a site where "Everyone except external users" exists without removing the "Everyone except external users" group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you cannot restrict the access of external vendors added as internal users in your Azure AD without removing "Everyone except external users" permissions from the SharePoint site.

You will have to remove the "Everyone except external users" group permissions from the site and then grant permissions to internal users separately.

Here's is what you can try:

1. Create a Azure AD security group only for all internal users (without external vendors added as internal users).
2. Remove the "Everyone except external users" group from site permissions.
3. Grant permissions to newly created Azure AD security group on the SharePoint site.

Comment: sounds like a plan, testing this tomorrow.